# Coloring the vertical lines by Class in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, line

I want to plot the distribution of a variable by Class and add vertical lines denoting the means of the subsets defined by each Class and having them colored by Class.  While I succeed to color the distributions by Class, the vertical lines appear gray.  For a reproducible example see below:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
mtcars[, am := factor(am, levels = c(1, 0))]
mean_data <- mtcars[, .(mu = mean(hp)), by = am]

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, fill = am , color = am)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity",alpha = 0.4) + guides(color = FALSE) +
  geom_density (alpha = 0.5)+ 
  geom_vline(data = mean_data, xintercept = mean_data$mu, aes(color = as.factor(mean_data$am)), size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  ggtitle("Hp by am") + scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("am" , "no am")) +
  labs(fill = "Transmission") + theme_economist()
```

This code renders the following plot:

[image]

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `xintercept` mapping in your `aes` call, so that `ggplot` properly maps all the aesthetics:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, fill = am , color = am)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity",alpha = 0.4) + guides(color = FALSE) +
    geom_density (alpha = 0.5)+ 
    geom_vline(data = mean_data, aes(xintercept = mu, color = as.factor(am)), size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
    ggtitle("Hp by am") + scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("am" , "no am")) +
    labs(fill = "Transmission") + theme_economist()
```

Anything you put in a `geom` call that's not in `aes` gets treated as a one-off value, and doesn't get all the mapped aesthetics applied to it.